# Issue with here package in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

The here package seems to not be working properly for me. When I run `here()` I get

```
Error in here() : argument "f" is missing, with no default
```

When I use `dr_here()` I get

```
here() starts at C:/Users/XXXX/YYYY/Documents.
- This directory contains a file ".here"
- Initial working directory: C:/Users/XXXX/YYYY/Documents
- Current working directory: C:/Users/XXXX/YYYY/Documents
```

I don't understand where the issue is?

Comment: try `here::here()` instead of just `here()`. The function `here` may be overwritten.

Comment: @danlooo is right, there is no f argument for here. The problem you are getting seems to be a "formula missing" that comes from another package